# Printing Columnwise in Excel using ORA_EXCEL package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using the ora_excel package to generate the Excel as below.

```
ColumnA 

Row1

Row2

Row3
```

Using the below procedure,

```
declare

  doc_id    pls_INTEGER:=0;
  sheet_id  pls_INTEGER:=0;
  row_id    pls_INTEGER:=0;

begin

  doc_id   := ora_excel.new_document;
  sheet_id := ora_excel.add_sheet('Sheet 1',doc_id);

  row_id   := ora_excel.add_row;
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('A','Row1', doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);

  row_id   := ora_excel.add_row;
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('A','Row2',doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);

  row_id   := ora_excel.add_row;
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('A','Row3', doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);

  ora_excel.save_to_file('FTP_FOLDER','excel.xlsx',doc_id);

end;
```

And its generating the Excel into the Specific Folder.

Now I wants to add a some record to `ColumnB` after printing all the rows of `ColumnA` as like below.

```
ColumnA ColumnB

Row1     Row1B

Row2     Row2B

Row3     Row3B
```

I am newbie to PL/SQL.

Could anyone help me to resolve the issue.

Is there anyway to navigate and update specific row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare

  doc_id    pls_INTEGER:=0;
  sheet_id  pls_INTEGER:=0;
  row_id    pls_INTEGER:=0;

begin

  doc_id   := ora_excel.new_document;
  sheet_id := ora_excel.add_sheet('Sheet 1',doc_id);

  row_id   := ora_excel.add_row;
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('A','Row1', doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('B','Row1B', doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);

  row_id   := ora_excel.add_row;
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('A','Row2',doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('B','Row2B', doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);

  row_id   := ora_excel.add_row;
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('A','Row3', doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('B','Row3B', doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);

  ora_excel.save_to_file('FTP_FOLDER','excel.xlsx',doc_id);

end;
```

Check this link: http://www.oraexcel.com/documentation/ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value

If ColumnA and ColumnB are populated at different times and from different sources, but before you write the excel data to file, then this code might work:

```
DECLARE

  doc_id    PLS_INTEGER:=0;
  sheet_id  PLS_INTEGER:=0;
  row_id    PLS_INTEGER:=0;
  v_idx     PLS_INTEGER;

 TYPE t_rowids_t IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER INDEXED BY PLS_INTEGER;
 vt_rowids t_rowids_t;
BEGIN

  doc_id   := ora_excel.new_document;
  sheet_id := ora_excel.add_sheet('Sheet 1',doc_id);

  --select from first table

  row_id   := ora_excel.add_row;
  vt_rowids(row_id) := row_id;
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('A','Row1', doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);

  row_id   := ora_excel.add_row;
  vt_rowids(row_id) := row_id;
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('A','Row2',doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);

  row_id   := ora_excel.add_row;
  vt_rowids(row_id) := row_id;
  ora_excel.set_cell_value('A','Row3', doc_id,sheet_id, row_id);

  --select from another table
  v_idx := vt_rowids.FIRST;

  WHILE v_idx IS NOT NULL
  LOOP
        ora_excel.set_cell_value('B','Row1B', doc_id,sheet_id, vt_rowids(v_idx)); 
        ora_excel.set_cell_value('B','Row2B', doc_id,sheet_id, vt_rowids(v_idx));
        ora_excel.set_cell_value('B','Row3B', doc_id,sheet_id, vt_rowids(v_idx));

        v_idx := vt_rowids.NEXT(v_idx);
  END LOOP;

  ora_excel.save_to_file('FTP_FOLDER','excel.xlsx',doc_id);

END;
```

Comment: Dear alexs, 

Thanks for your reply, But We could not get the value for Column B at the time of adding a new Row. ColumnA and ColumB will be from different tables based on certain condtions.

Comment: Need to checkout alexs, I will let you know once I got seated. :-) Thanks for your follow-up.